# Split strings in list with condition and create a new list

Tags: python, string, split

**Background:** I'm analyzing music genres of various songs. From my original dataframe, I extracted the list of genres and turned it into a list below.

> genres = ['pop', 'edm', 'argentine hip hop', 'rock', 'trap latino', 'r&b', 'latin hip hop', 'latin pop']

**What I want to do:** I'm tyring to count the amount of high level genres. For example, with this list above, "pop" and "uk pop" would be considered two different items as is vs. being counted as one.

**What I've done:** I tried using the .split(" ") method and assigning it to a new list.

```
genres = ['pop', 'edm', 'argentine hip hop', 'rock', 'trap latino', 'r&b', 'latin hip hop', 'uk pop']
genres_split = []
for z in genres:
    genres_split.append(z.split(' '))
        
print(genres_split)
```

**Output:**

```
    [['pop'], ['edm'], ['argentine', 'hip', 'hop'], ['rock'], ['trap', 'latino'], ['r&b'], ['latin', 'hip', 'hop'], ['uk', 'pop']]
```

**Problem:**

1. **"Hip Hop":** The split method turns the term "hip hop" into two separate terms. **Is there a way to ignore this?**
2. **List within list:** **Is there a different approach I can use that will allow me to extract all of the terms and save it in a list?**

Comment: You could explain this better. What is the desired output? You can't say split but don't split.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a good idea to replace `hip hop` with `hip-hop`, that will resolve your problem.
About you problem with nested list:

```
for z in genres:
    x = z.split(' ')
    for a in x:
        genres_split.append(a)
        
print(genres_split)
```